# Lambda does not appear in dropdown for User Migration Lambda Trigger

Tags: triggers, amazon-cognito

The Lambda I created appears in every other dropdown for every other trigger type, but does not appear in the User Migration or Pre-Token generation ones for some reason. There is zero documentation on why this could be and I'm very confused!

Comment: Hey have you a solution yet? I am having the same issue :/